# Dell T3500 Precision Workstation will not boot after an update from 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, kernel

I'm having trouble booting ubuntu after upgrading to 10.10.

After the unexpected exit with status 0x0009 message, it said:

```
Gave up waiting for root device: common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- check rootdelay = (did system wait long enough?)
- Check root = (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing moduloes (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/(some big name for my hard drive) does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.13.3 ...
(initramfs)
```

This [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1595809) describes the problem that many people are having with T3500 and Ubuntu 10.10.

I was able to boot an older kernel, but I'd like to get this working with the latest kernel.

working kernel `uname -a` reads `Linux workstation 2.6.32-25-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 19:52:42 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

not-working kernel = `2.6.35-22-generic`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a driver needed for your root filesystem is missing. I would open a bug against the kernel (`ubuntu-bug linux`) and then try to narrow down what driver is in used with the old kernel that is missing for the new kernel. (Compare `/proc/modules` between the good kernel and the bad kernel -- you should be able to get the contents from the busybox prompt.)